# Posting data to Django with Ajax, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, geolocation

I would like to submit the html5 geolocation data to the django admin backend. However I am not sure if the javascript, jQuery and ajax is set up correctly in the index.html javascript . I am able to display the latitude and longitude in the html page but am unable to post the data to django. Is there someone kind enough to help correct where I might have gone wrong. I have been working on it for a  week being a newbie. Would truly appreciate any help. Thank you.

The code that works so far is below. The file structure of the django app is as below:

```
-ajax
   - __pycache__
   - migrations
        - __pycache__
          0001_initial.py
          __init__.py
   - static
        - css
            - bootstrap.css
        - fonts
        - js
            - script.js
   - templates
        - ajax
            - base.html
            - index.html
        - __init__.py
        - admin.py
        - apps.py
        - models.py
        - tests.py
        - urls.py
        - views.py

-server
   - __pycache__
   - __init__.py
   - settings.py
   - urls.py
   - views.py
   - wsgi.py

-db.sqlite3
-manage.py
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'ajax/base.html' %}
{% block body %}
<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Get Your Location</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<button type="button" id="btn_submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" disabled>Submit</button>
{% endblock %}
```

script.js

```
var pos;

var $demo;

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    $demo.text("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  pos = position;
  var { latitude, longitude } = pos.coords;
  $demo.html(`Latitude: ${latitude}<br>Longitude: ${longitude}`);
  $('#btn_submit').attr("disabled", null);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $demo = $("#demo");
  $('#btn_submit').on('click', function() {
    var data = pos.coords;
    data.csrfmiddlewaretoken = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
    $.post("/echo/html/", data, function() {
      alert("Saved Data!");
    });
  });
});
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'ajax/css/bootstrap.css' %}"/>
</head>
<body>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 well">
        <h3 class="text-primary">Python - Django Simple Submit Form With Ajax</h3>
        <hr style="border-top:1px dotted #000;"/>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
<script src = "{% static 'ajax/js/jquery-3.2.1.js' %}"></script>
<script src = "{% static 'ajax/js/script.js' %}"></script>
</html>
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Member
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Member)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Member(models.Model):
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=16)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=16)
```

views.py (ajax app)

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Member
#from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
# Create your views here.
#@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'ajax/index.html')

#@csrf_exempt 
def insert(request):
    member = Member(latitude=request.POST['latitude'], longitude=request.POST['longitude'])
    member.save()
    return redirect('/')
```

urls.py (ajax app)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
    url(r'^insert$', views.insert, name="insert")
]
```

views.py (server)

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def index_redirect(request):
    return redirect('/ajax/')
```

urls.py (server)

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index_redirect, name="index_redirect"),
    url(r'^ajax/', include("ajax.urls")),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: I'm not seeing `$position` defined or set anywhere. Even if you changed that to `position`, it's not defined outside your `showPosition`

Comment: Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/srhgnvqe/

Comment: having a look now, thanks Chris!

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for the help. I went through it as much as I could and tried to find other similar examples of posting to django admin site in the web. The code did manage to post according to the terminal but the latitude and longitude is not shown in the django admin page after I created a superuser to check the result. Where does .post(/echo/html/, data, ...) in script.js posts to? Is there changes that need to be made in views.py or urls.py to POST the data to the model.py? The views.py and urls.py files have remained the same as before. Sorry for having so many questions. Thank you

Comment: `/echo/html/` is specific to jsfiddle; you need to use the actual route of your POST request. I'm guessing something like `/ajax/insert`...?

Comment: oh, i forgot to mention that i edited the question and file structure above. Will try your suggestion now.

Comment: unfortunately for me, it is still not posting. hmm

Comment: I suggest to use postman to figure out the correct endpoint and parameters. Once you have that, you can move forward with your AJAX code.

Comment: ok, am looking into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most probable reason is because you don't have the CSRF Token tag in the template.

You have to put it in the template like this:

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

You can also define that a view doesn't need the CSRF Token putting the decorator *csrf_exempt* :

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello world')
```

Hope that it helps you!

Comment: Thank you. It helped, I added the code as you suggested. But am still not able to post to the django admin site.